# Magento Curl xml data

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, xml, shipping-methods, curl

I want to get live rates of all shipping methods of TNT Lebanon between origin and delivery address.
Like Road Express, Overnight Express, Overnight PAYU Satchel, 9:00 Express, 10:00 Express, etc.

I am using below code.

```
$url = 'http://app.thenetmanager.net/pos/POSWS.asmx?op=CalculatePOSOrderPrice';

$xmlRequest = "<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <CalculatePOSOrderPrice xmlns="http://posws.org/">
            <userIdentifier>69741684-B9DA-404D-833D-1DE02F11154E</userIdentifier>
            <serviceID>70</serviceID>
            <shipperCity>LEBANON</shipperCity>
            <consigneeCountry>TRIPOLI</consigneeCountry>
            <consigneeCity>opentext</consigneeCity>
            <isDocument>false</isDocument>
            <weight>0.6</weight>
            <specialDelivery>-1</specialDelivery>
            <goodsValue>10.0</goodsValue>
            <goodsDescription>description</goodsDescription>
            <addPacking>false</addPacking>
            <addFumigation>false</addFumigation>
            <addPermit>false</addPermit>
            <addInsurance>false</addInsurance>
        </CalculatePOSOrderPrice>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$xmlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($xmlResponse);
```

But gives me an empty message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is connected with double (`"`) quotation marks, in which you’ve wrapped your xml-request (you can also find them there). Your php-code is interpreted in a wrong way because of it and you are not getting the correct result.

[image: phpstorm]

Try to replace the double quotation marks with the with single ones (`'`) and change:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
```

with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xmlRequest)));
```

**Updated final code:**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://app.thenetmanager.net/pos/POSWS.asmx?op=CalculatePOSOrderPrice';
        $xmlRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <CalculatePOSOrderPrice xmlns="http://posws.org/">
            <userIdentifier>69741684-B9DA-404D-833D-1DE02F11154E</userIdentifier>
            <serviceID>70</serviceID>
            <shipperCity>LEBANON</shipperCity>
            <consigneeCountry>TRIPOLI</consigneeCountry>
            <consigneeCity>opentext</consigneeCity>
            <isDocument>false</isDocument>
            <weight>0.6</weight>
            <specialDelivery>-1</specialDelivery>
            <goodsValue>10.0</goodsValue>
            <goodsDescription>description</goodsDescription>
            <addPacking>false</addPacking>
            <addFumigation>false</addFumigation>
            <addPermit>false</addPermit>
            <addInsurance>false</addInsurance>
        </CalculatePOSOrderPrice>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xmlRequest)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        $xmlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($xmlResponse);
        curl_close($ch);
```

**Result (debug):**

[image: Result]

**Result (plain):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CalculatePOSOrderPriceResponse xmlns="http://posws.org/"><CalculatePOSOrderPriceResult>-1</CalculatePOSOrderPriceResult></CalculatePOSOrderPriceResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

PS: This is just my opinion, in case it won’t help, please, edit the code and get back here.

Comment: i got this message `soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 3.`

Comment: @mahmoudismail > you should delete the space between <? and xml. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282467/name-cannot-begin-with-the-character)

Comment: Oki , again i got an empty message :)

Comment: @mahmoudismail I’ve updated my answer

Comment: @mahmoudismail Always welcome :)

Comment: How to get userIdentifier?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Try to address your question to mahmoudismail (the person who has submitted the question)

Comment: OK. @mahmoudismail How to get userIdentifier?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani , userIdentifier is in my case the user identifier for the TNT account.

Comment: @mahmoudismail Thanks for your reply. But how can I get that ? I have only tnt email-id and password.

Comment: You can get that from TNT Support. contact them. Regards :)